# OOPS : the __cmp__ function

Tags: c++, python, oop

Does python internally overload the "==" when I implement the `__cmp__` function in my class, just how we  do that in C++  ?

Just curious. I am new to python. :)

Comment: It's unclear exactly what your question is, but whatever it is the answer is probably here: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of `==` as used in your Python code changes when you define `__cmp__`. In this particular sense, the "==-operator" on the Python level is modified by your definition of `__cmp__` (note that this is only true if you don't also define `__eq__`).

But the `operator==` on the C++ level is not affected by this, for two reasons:

- Python isn't implemented in C++, but in C, and there is no operator overloading
- Python itself isn't recompiled when you write or use your Python code

Comment: By python level is it meant that It will be changed globally ?

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi No, only in your code (and anything that imports it).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, along with `__eq__`,  `__ne__`   `__lt__`, 
`__le__`, 
`__gt__`
and `__ge__`[(doc)](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to what?  That's what `__cmp__` is *for*.

Though it's been deprecated for a while, and it's gone in 3 entirely, and you should use [`__eq__` and friends](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and likewise with a lot of other operators and methods. There's a full listing in the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames).